# Implement multi select lookup using listbox control in aspx page

Tags: development, javascript, sharepoint-addin, asp.net, ajax

How can I implement the multi look up select list items functionality in SharePoint using asp.net C#?

Please help me with some code, I am using two list boxes and have added a add remove button on the page, but I have set postback true on listbox item.

So the page posts back once I select any item. I do not want this to happen as I just want to move items from one listbox control to another.

I have used JavaScript to move items but since lookup items are rendered like `88;#name`, I am not able to save it, as JavaScript will only move the item and it will not consider it as lookup item.

In short I just want a nice solution to implement the below functionality in an asp.net c# page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How are you fetching values for left side list box? Anyway you should be able to do this using normal html list box and javascript to move items left to right.

Comment: I am using a list to load the values into the left listbox
Yes i can move, but since its a lookup while saving the data back to the list it will throw an error, as lookup is rendered in a different way

Comment: so can you clarify what exactly is the issue when you copy items from left to right what is the issue? you can always manipulate the values while posting the data using jquery/javascript.

Comment: The items in my listbox are coming from a SharePoint List, so when it is rendered it will be rendered as <option value="1">SP

Comment: Ok you can always manipulate what you want to show in list box using js..